# UK - What if only one tenant can prove right-to-rent?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, immigration

I'm doing right-to-rent checks on prospective tenants. They are a couple, one of them can give me a share code, the other one cannot (yet). Can I let the house to just the one person, and allow the other person to stay there as a guest until they get their share code? Or would I be running the risk of getting fined for allowing someone without right-to-rent to stay there?

Comment: This sounds a little like a request for advice.  It would be better rewritten into the third person or something.

Comment: This seems a bit odd, why would it take so long to get a share code?